# apex - Messaging.sendEmail fails with TargetObjectId as UserId

Tags: apex

I want to send an email to Opportunity owner from apex. 
Its a VF Email Template with recipientType="User" and relatedToType="Quote"

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    EmailTemplate template = [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Template_Unique_Name'];

    mail.setTemplateId(template.id);                              
    mail.setWhatId(QuoteId);
    mail.setTargetObjectId(OppOwnerId);  
    mail.saveAsActivity = false;    

    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Error:- 
System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked that the value in  `OppOwnerId ` is a user ID immediately before you make the `setTargetObjectId` call?

Comment: @KeithC yes     OppOwnerId is a correct user id.

Comment: We would have to see the code where OppOwnerId is being set. I suspect that value is wrong or null.

Comment: @greenstork Values are set properly. I even tried with direct IDs instead of OppOwnerId and QuoteId, but I get same error.

Comment: I noticed that Email is sent if I have Site Guest User as Opportunity Owner, but the merge field values related to Quote are not correct in sent email.